# Handling Immersive sticky on lower api levels

Tags: java, android

The problem is that I need to set the minimum api level to 10.

When I attempt to build whilst referencing a property such as

```
SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
```

I get the following error:

`cannot find symbol[javac] symbol  : variable SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY`

I have used reflection to handle function calls that are specific to api levels above api 10, but haven't had any luck in doing the same for values such as enums.

I know I have the option to just use the constants values and only call `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility` if the api level is kitkat or greater, but ideally i'd like to use the enums, incase the values ever change.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: "I get the following error" -- set your `compileSdkVersion` to 19 or higher.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I was setting the value in the wrong place. Feel free to change your comment to a question so I can mark it as the correct answer